# How to 'break' if statement in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a small part of my code

```
def menu():
    choices = ["Create a Scenario", "Load a Database", "Quit"]
    m1 = eg.choicebox("What would you like to do?", "Greenfly Model Menu", choices)
    if m1 == "Load a Scenario":
        dbless = eg.enterbox("What is the name of your database?")
        if dbless is None:
            menu()
        db_name = dbless + ".db"
        check = os.path.isfile(db_name)
```

If the variable *dbless* ends up being *None* the code ends up running the *menu()* function as its suppose to. However, one the rest of the code finishes executing, the rest of this function ends up running. Is there anyway to make it so the rest of the function not to run.

Comment: `break` statements can be issued only inside the loops. Here use `return` statement.

Comment: Try to return something maybe. Like this: `return`

Comment: You could `break` if you used a loop instead of recursion, which is also a better way to solve the problem.

Comment: Or put the rest of the code in `else:`. But what @jonrsharpe says, don't use recursion here.

Comment: Could you please correct your indentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include a `while` loop so that until the input is not None, it will ask for the input:

```
while dbless is None:
    menu()
else:  #you can remove the else and unindent the next two lines, but I'm used to do it that way
    db_name = dbless + ".db"
    check = os.path.isfile(db_name)
```

The problem I see here is that it will indefinitely ask fo the input. If you have a problem with that, you can add something like an `attempt` to that while, but I don't think that's the case. Also, I am not sure if that code would really work because of calling the function again... anyway, give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Use `return` statement instead of considering `break` inside the function without loop.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use a break statement outside a loop. Therefore you need to use the return statement. You can do that in two ways.

```
if dbless is None:
    menu()
    return
```

or

```
if dbless is None:
    return menu()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this and it will be consistent with your logic:

```
def menu():
    choices = ["Create a Scenario", "Load a Database", "Quit"]
    m1 = eg.choicebox("What would you like to do?", "Greenfly Model Menu", choices)
    if m1 == "Load a Scenario":
    dbless = eg.enterbox("What is the name of your database?")
    flag=0
    while flag<1:
        if dbless is None:
            menu()
            break
        db_name = dbless + ".db"
        check = os.path.isfile(db_name) 
        flag+=1
```